# $\int(\sin x)(\sqrt x-\frac1{4x\sqrt x})dx=\sin x f(x)-\sqrt xg(x)+c,$

Tags: integration

> Let $\int(\sin x)(\sqrt x-\frac1{4x\sqrt x})dx=\sin x f(x)-\sqrt xg(x)+c,$ where $c$ is a constant of integration. Then, find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

My attempt: $\frac{4x^2-1}{4x\sqrt x}$. Not getting anything. I wonder if  I could substitute $\cos x$, that way I can eliminate $\sin x dx$. But not able to do so. Or, maybe putting $\sqrt x$ as $\cos^2\theta$, but not able to move ahead.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad Thanks. Will edit my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{gather}
I = \int \sin x\sqrt{x}dx - \int\frac{\sin x}{4x\sqrt x}dx\\
= -\cos x \sqrt x + \int \frac{\cos x}{2 \sqrt x}dx - \int\frac{\sin x}{4x\sqrt x}dx\\
= -\cos x \sqrt x + \frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt x} + \int\frac{\sin x}{4x\sqrt x}dx - \int\frac{\sin x}{4x\sqrt x}dx \\
\boxed{I = -\cos x \sqrt x + \frac{\sin x}{2\sqrt x} + c}
\end{gather}$$